# RaisedButton Material UI problema disabled

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs

tengo un RaisedButton de material UI, le agrego la propiedad disabled:true, lo muestra bloqueado pero al momento de presionar ejecuta igualmente la acción, a que se puede deber esto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: puedes mostrar tu código ?

Comment: estimado, modifiqué la pregunta agregando una imagen de un fragmento del codigo

Comment: Qué versión de react usas? En qué browsers lo has probado? Aparentemente algunos browsers ignoran por completo la propiedad disabled https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11588#issuecomment-345734269

Comment: desconozco como buscar específicamente la version de react, pero ejecute estos comandos:

node --version
v8.11.1

npm --version
5.6.0

Comment: Rodrigo por favor incluye un [mcve], las imágenes de código no son de ayuda